# UITabBar remove the black background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

As the title states, I haven't been successful in removing the black background in the UITabBar.

I know it is possible to add a subview on top of it. But I want it to be transparent so if I add a transparent subview on top of it, it will just have the underlying black color.

Setting the tintColor made me able to change the color of the UITabBar, but when I change it to clearColor it will just be black again.

Anybody know how to remove the underlying image or color so it will be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

When they added the `tintColor` property in iOS 5, they also added a number of other appearance-customization functionality to `UITabBar`. See, `backgroundImage` and `selectionIndicatorImage`, and the `finishedSelectedImage` and `finishedUnselectedImage` properties of `UITabBarItem`.